# Render JSON in Groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have the following code to implement JSON in Groovy:

```
def index = {
    def list = WordList.list()
    render(contentType:"text/json"){
        LISTS {
            for(item in list){
                LIST (NAME: item.name, ID: item.id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which almost works but it doesnt show multiple results i.e. the NAME and ID fields get overwritten on each cycle resulting in only the last record getting returned. What is the correct syntax to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list = WordList.list()
list = list.collect { [name: it.name, id: it.id] }

render(contentType: 'application/json') {
   [lists: list]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do i add the JSON tag 'LIST' before each separate name/id?

Comment: You can't have a map with multiple identical keys

Comment: Yea, what tim_yates said.  Once you realize JSON is just a MAP, it will make things easier on you.

Answer (score 3):

My solution in this case is to construct the JSON map explicitly, then render it as JSON.

An example:

```
def list = WordList.list()
def json = []
list.each{ item ->
    json << [name: item.name, id: item.id]
}
render json as JSON
```

You will need to import grails.converters.JSON to use this method.